# Checking instance of specific python module

Tags: python, request

While writing a test for my API I discovered this that I don't quite understand.

`r` is the response from an API call.

Why is this `True`:

```
isinstance(r, requests.Response)
```

And why is this `False`:

```
isinstance(r.__class__, requests.models.Response)
```

Given that

```
r.__class__ == requests.models.Response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isinstance(r, requests.Response)` checks if `r` is a `Response` or subclass, which it clearly is.

`isinstance(r.__class__, requests.models.Response)` checks if `Response` is a `Response`, which it is clearly not: `Response` is a `type`.

What you probably meant with the second check is `issubclass(type(r), requests.model.Response)`. Personally, I prefer using `type` to `__class__` in these situations, mostly because I have an irrational fear of `__class__` getting bound to the wrong thing somehow, or not being available.